# Using playlistitem.insert via one link

Tags: excel, vba, api, http, youtube

I've been able to do video searches and read info using just one link that starts with googleapis.com but for the playlistitemsinsert to put videos into a playlist, I'm having trouble with the syntax. I'm trying to randomize the order of videos in a YouTube playlist. I understand you can shuffle play but its easier for me to remove the videos if they're played in chronological order, also its easier to go back to a video you recently watched.

I have all of the video ids in a column in excel I'm just not sure how to use vba to do a POST HTTP request to insert the videos into a playlist. Can you help me with the syntax on this?

Answer (score 0):

Although not using excel as database This works using youtube api. and users youtube created play list . shuffles the play list into new order every time page is refreshes

1. Load YT-player API.
2. Load YT-playlist user playlist id "**.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo16_*******"
3. To Shuffle playlist use > *player.setShuffle(true);*
4. To Start YT-player at video 1 in shuffled playlist use > *player.playVideoAt(0)*

working demo [Responsive shuffled YouTube Playlist on Google sites](https://sites.google.com/view/shuffled-api-list-player/home)

code [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jcb01/xo5tb4u9/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Responsive YouTube shuffled playlist player -->
<head>
<base target="_top">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag.  
style =  replaces  size in the player script makes it responsive -->

<div style=" top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" 
id='player'>
</div>
</body>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
playerVars: {
  autoplay: 0,
  loop: 1,
  controls: 1,
  showinfo: 1,
  frameborder: 1,
  'listType': 'playlist',
  'list': "PLo16_DLriHp4A8BvkJFZfO_4KDVv7yGgy", // your YouTube playlist id here
 },

 events: {
  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
 }
 });
 }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.

 function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // first shuffle play list 

 player.setShuffle(true); 

  // Onload and on refresh shuffles the users YT playlist but always starts playing 
  // the first video in the original list at its new index position 
  //ie. video (1) = video( new shuffled pos ?)
  // to get over this we can start the player at the new shuffled playlist 
  //video 1(index=0) this changes every time it's refreshed

 player.playVideoAt(0) 

 }
  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //  option to to add bits         
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  const player = event.target;
 }

 </script>

 </html>
```